# Counting a specific letter in C?

Tags: c

I have to make a program that counts how many times the letter'A' has been used in a string. So just the capital letter A.

I've got this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char s[30];
int amount=0;
printf("Enter a string \n");
gets(s);

//???

printf("\nThe letter A has been used %i times\n", amount);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you having trouble with constructing the logic to solving it, or its syntax related?

Comment: expect senior members to put you through hell for this question :)
better show your attempts, and where you failed ?

Comment: Okay... you remember the last question you just posted and I posted an answer to it?  Remember that `if(s[i] == ' ') { /*do stuff*/ }`  Apply it here.

Comment: What @nhgrif said, and use a `for` loop to iterate through the chars in `s`.

Comment: If you want to be a good programmer, you need to start seeing similarities in the problems you're solving.  This is a variation on the question you just had answered for you... and its only been 30 minutes...

Comment: Hey nhgrif, thanks for helping me out on that other question. I've been stuck on these two for quite some time since I'm so used to Java... I'll try to apply your tips, also the one of you mbratch. Thanks.

Comment: `s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'a'` should be enough help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `gets` automatically inserts the terminating `\0` for you, it's simple:

```
char s[30];
int amount=0;
int i = 0;
printf("Enter a string \n");
gets(s);

for (; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'a') amount++;
}


printf("\nThe letter A has been used %i times\n", amount);
```

Comment: Well this isn't going to work either :-(

Comment: @squeamish Feel free to note what's wrong with my code. I seem to be derping right now.

Comment: Looks OK now :-) Maybe it was just me

Comment: Why all this complication instead of just `s[i] == 'A'`?

Comment: Ahh, I actually got close to the same with your tips (; Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: @Warow I would unaccept my answer until it's confirmed that it's actually correct. I'm uncertain from the comments.

Comment: I tried your code remyabel. It worked, however I did remove '|| s[i] == 'a''.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do the job is a loop that compare every char of the string  with the wanted one ('A' in this case) until you find '\0' ... in alternative `strchr` can be used to achieve this (just to show a different approach).

```
  int count = 0;
  char *p=strchr(s,'A');
  while (p!=NULL) {
    count++;
    p=strchr(p+1,'A');
  }
```